# Why is 22 the default port number for SFTP?

Tags: ftp, port, sftp

Why is 22 the default port number for SFTP? Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming at all.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's the default [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) port and SFTP is usually carried over an SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 17):

Why is 21 the default port for FTP? Or 80 the default for HTTP? It is a convention.

Comment: Thats why i am asking this. Is there any specific reason for this?. What will happen if i provide someother number.

Comment: Nothing will happen if the port you served is not blocked or preserved. Those ports are called "Well known ports" so that you can write a program like FileZilla where the standard-port for connections is 21 or 22 but you can change it to any belief.

Comment: If you change the port on the server, you need to explicitly tell your client to connect to that new port rather then the default one which you don't usually need to specify. Though this could decrease bot login attempts.

Comment: You can configure your server to listen to other port number instead of default one. But in this case, the client must also specify this during connection attempt.

Comment: Because ftp is 21, and http://cdn3.sbnation.com/imported_assets/761831/spinal-tap-amp-11.jpg

Answer (score 5):

From Wikipedia:

> Applications implementing common
>   services often use specifically
>   reserved, well-known port numbers for
>   receiving service requests from client
>   hosts. This process is known as
>   listening and involves the receipt of
>   a request on the well-known port and
>   reestablishing one-to-one
>   server-client communications on
>   another private port, so that other
>   clients may also contact the
>   well-known service port. The
>   well-known ports are defined by
>   convention overseen by the Internet
>   Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA).

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_and_UDP_port)

So as others mentioned, it's a convention.

Answer (score 2):

Not authoritative, but interesting: 21 is FTP, 23 is telnet.  22 is SSH...something in between (that can take the place of both).

Answer (score 0):

Ahem, because 22 is the port number for ssh and has been for ages?